# PHP error relating to file-paths?

Tags: php

So I'm just learning PHP. I am trying to run my login script that I built, and I'm getting this error.

```
Warning: require_once(../../configs/db_config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\includes\logininc.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../configs/db_config.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\assets\includes\logininc.php on line 4
```

Is this because this path is incorrect?

This code is on page.

```
require_once "../../configs/db_config.php";
require_once "../../includes/memberfunc.php";
```

db_config sits in a folder below the directory of the page that I ran (logininc.php)

Update : Here's the code in question. It sits in the base directory next to index.php

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" action="assets/includes/logininc.php"> <fieldset> 
  <legend>Login </legend> 
  <p>Please enter your username and password to access the administrator's panel</p>

   <label for="username"> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />Username: </label> <label for="password"> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />Password: </label> <label for="submit"> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" /> </label> </fieldset> </form>
```

Comment: Goes like this. Index > assets. In assets there are 2 folders, includes, configs. In includes sits logininc.php.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**DIR**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php#constant.dir) to specificy a path relative to the current file:

```
require_once __DIR__ "/../../configs/db_config.php";
```

Otherwise the path is relative to the directory that contains the script where execution started.

Answer (score 0):

Given the (made up) path `/home/sites/example.com/html/logininc.php`, then

`../../configs/db_config.php` would evaluate to `/home/sites/configs/db_config.php`
and
`../../includes/memberfunc.php` would evalate to `/home/sites/includes/memberfunc.php`.

If, as you say, db_config sits in a folder BELOW the directory where logininc.php sits, then you'd want something more like

```
require('subdir/logininc.php');
```

Comment: No luck it seems.

I tried 'require('configs/db_config.php');
require('includes/memberfunc');'

This is my file structure. test/assets/includes/logininc.php and test/assets/configs/db_connect.php? 

Ugh so frustrating. Maybe I need to put logininc.php into my base directory as login.php makes the call to  logininc.php which is located well above it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . "/configs/db_config.php";
```

Adjust the number of `dirname` according to the directory level. To debug the path:

```
echo dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . "/configs/db_config.php";
```

Comment: So does dirname make it look down level. So if I was at test1/test2/test3 dirname the first time would be test1, then dirname again test2 and so on?

Comment: Reversed, if you are in file `1/2/3/file.php`, first `dirname` is `1/2/3`, second `dirname` is `1/2`, third `dirname` is `3`.

Comment: ...where the first dirname is the innermost and the last dirname is the outermost.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Failed to open stream` and `No such file or directory` mean that you are trying to require or include a file that does not exist in the specified directory.

This can happen for a couple of reasons:

- The file you are trying to require does not exist
- You are specifying a wrong path

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Others pointed out, your path is wrong.

```
.. means you are going back a directory from the current
```

You mention that your are a beginner , I advice you to always specify the full path until you are comfortable

Edit:
 if both configs and includes are in assets then they should be like this:

```
require_once("/test/assets/configs/db_config.php"); 
require_once("/test/assets/includes/memberfunc.php");
```

This way you will never get confused

Comment: Hi this makes sense, thanks for that but I'm STILL getting this error. Can you take another look at my original question because I have updated it with some possibly relevant code that I mistakenly omitted...?

Answer (score 0):

for dubugging, or finding exactly where require_once expects your file to be located, use [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php), which will provide you absolute path. Then, you can decide how to navigate from there, meaning to add/remove the number of `..`s

`echo realpath("../../configs/db_config.php");`